# Using With clause in sqlite3; are the results of with clause saved and reused?

Tags: sql, sqlite, common-table-expression

```
with 
printercheck as (SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM available_material_printmode_config 
WHERE printer_name ='123' LIMIT 1) as p),
materialcheck as (SELECT case when material_name is null  then 0 else 1 end as m 
FROM available_material_printmode_config WHERE printer_name ='123' 
and printmode_name = '2' LIMIT 1)

select m.name from material m 

left join available_material_printmode_config ac on ac.material_name = m.name 
and (select p from printercheck limit 1) 
and (select m from materialcheck limit 1)

left join available_materials am1 on am1.material_name = m.name 
and ((select p from printercheck limit 1) != 1 
or ((select p from printercheck limit 1) 
and (select m from materialcheck limit 1) !=1 ))

where
case
when (select p from printercheck limit 1) and (select m from materialcheck limit 1)
then
ac.printer_name = '123' and ac.printmode_name = '2'
else
am1.printer_name = '123'
end
```

I have a sqlite3 query looking like this, wanted to know if printercheck and materialcheck will be executed/ fetched for each row of main query or will they be executed once and result will be stored and reused.

If printercheck and materialcheck will be executed for each row of main query then how to avoid it and reuse the result of printercheck and materialcheck by executing them once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good question, because different databases handle CTEs differently.  For instance, SQL Server never materializes CTEs.  Oracle often does.

According to the SQLite [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html):

> An ordinary common table expression works as if it were a view that
>   exists for the duration of a single statement. Ordinary common table
>   expressions are useful for factoring out subqueries and making the
>   overall SQL statement easier to read and understand.

Based on this documentation, I would say that SQLite does not materialize ordinary CTEs (recursive CTEs are a different beast).  If you want a temporary table, then explicitly use one.

Comment: Are you refering to Views when you mentioned temporary table? are results from view saved and reused?  SQlite3

Comment: "*SQL Server never materializes CTEs*" - the "never" is hard to believe. What happens when the size of a CTE exceeds the available memory?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . An an example, here is the request for a compiler hint to such a thing (https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/218968/provide-a-hint-to-force-intermediate-materialization-of-ctes-or-derived-tables).  In SQL Server, a CTE is simply a static replacement of the code into the query.

Comment: @SatyamRaikar . . . Views are not materialized by default in any database.